# Can AwesomeWM give multiple screens access to the same tagged clients?

Tags: multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

I have two (identical) monitors connected to the same graphics card, and am running AwesomeWM. The default configuration has nine tags, basically giving me 18 desktops (nine on the left, nine on the right).

I don't really want to divide my life into "left desktop stuff" and "right desktop stuff". Is there a way of configuring AwesomeWM to just provide nine desktops corresponding to the nine tags, so that the two screens can each be configured to display any of the nine, independently of one another?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to move tags across the screens on demand. So you achieve what you want, you need to modify the taglist to show the tags for every screen (and sort them by name) using the `source` and `filter` property. Then, in your `buttons` section, just add `t.screen = mouse.screen` in the line before the line that selects the tag.